# Combining rows and columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert my rows into columns, or my columns into rows... I am a little confused with which it is exactly but here's what I would want it to look like

Original table:

```
Month | Price
1       500  
2       600
3       700
```

what it needs to look like:

```
 1     2     3
500   600   700
```

Could anyone tell me how his could be done?

EDIT:

```sql
CREATE table #yourtable     (
   [Id] int, 
   [Value] varchar(6), 
   [ColumnName] varchar(13)) ;      
INSERT INTO #yourtable     (
   [Id], 
   [Value], 
   [ColumnName]) 
VALUES     
   (1, '1', 'Month'),     
   (2, '500', 'Price') ;   

select 
   Month, 
   Price 
from (   
   select 
      value, 
      columnname   
   from #yourtable ) d 
pivot 
  (max(value)   for columnname in (Month, Price) ) piv;
```

Comment: "I am trying to convert my rows into columns" - please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: `CREATE table #yourtable
    ([Id] int, [Value] varchar(6), [ColumnName] varchar(13))
;
    
INSERT INTO #yourtable
    ([Id], [Value], [ColumnName])
VALUES
    (1, '1', 'Month'),
    (2, '500', 'Price')
;


select Month, Price
from
(
  select value, columnname
  from #yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for columnname in (Month, Price)
) piv;`

I have tried this but this just gives it to me rows as the original

Comment: Try to add some info to your question, like answers to: 1) Can there be multiple records for a month?  What is the maximum number of records? 3) What should happen when there are records with month=`12,1,2` (a year break) ?

Comment: @Larnu, It does not :( is there a way to replace the headers with the month? I apologize for being a noob, I dont understand

Comment: The column name *would* be the month with that solution, @Kibofigs , as you would have `Month IN ([1], [2], [3])`. `[1], [2], [3]` are your column names.

Comment: @Kibofigs: comments which contain code should be added to your question using [edit].

Comment: @Luuk, I'm sorry... I did not know

Comment: You are probably looking for `Pivot` and `Unpivot`. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql/) out.

Comment: Try to repeat the example give in the docs: [FROM - Using PIVOT (and UNPIVOT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Your DDL and sample data table aren't the same; which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote an almost correct query.

```
select 
    Month, 
   Price 
from (   
   select 
      value, 
      columnname   
   from #yourtable) d 
pivot 
  (max(value)   for columnname in ('Month' AS Month, 'Price' AS Price) ) piv;
```

Comment: this returns a syntax error on Month, though...

Comment: It could be problem with reserved naming.. try `Month_` or something else..

Comment: any name throws the error :(